# fill randomly an array in Excel with 0 and 1 without repeating 1

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to fill randomly an array in Excel with 0 and 1 but with 1 just one time;

I have tried this formula but it fails:

```
  =IF(COUNTIF($K$43:K43;1)=1;1;0)
```

My table using :

=RANDBETWEEN(0;1)

```
0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0
```

Result of my formula:

```
0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I want the result of 1 just one time:

```
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Do you want to fill in the results *randomly* (as your question states) or *deterministically* as your formula suggests?  Perhaps the original table is filled in randomly and you want to select the first 1. But, if so, in the resulting table the location of the first 1 will be biased to the smaller indices. Your question is quite unclear, please explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `COUNTIF` is still 1 at stage `0 0 0 0 1 0`.

Please use formula as below (eg: if output required on L43)

```
L43=IF(AND(COUNTIF($K$43:K43,1)=1,L42=0),1,0)
```

Refer my [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsJwa.jpg).

Comment: i have just replaced L42 with with K and it resolved my problem, thanks, i have used this method to generat an array of 0,1, probably there is another easieste method...thanks